# How can I get a LAMP stack application in docker to send an HTTP POST to another service running on my local host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a simple web application that uses `HTML` and `PHP` to capture information via a `HTML` form. It take this information and uses `HTML-POST` to sent it to a service, also running on my local host on port 8400, as application `XML`. I have this application running in a `LAMP` stack on `macOS` and it works perfectly. The `XML` gets to the service without any issues.

When I moved this app into a containerized `LAMP` stack using `Docker`, the application runs, but when my `PHP` tries to post it to the other service running on port 8400, it cannot get there.

I am confident that this is an issue with `Docker` networking, but I am not sure what the problem is. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "1.0"
services:
  php:
    build: "./php/"
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: "./apache/"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

I think the answer probably lies in the allowing the container to reach my localhost network, but being relatively new to `Docker`, I am unsure.

How can I configure `Docker` networking to allow posting to services outside of `Dockernet` on specific ports?

Comment: What's the thing on port 8400...where's it running, what service is calling it, and how?  Every container can reach _its own_ "localhost network", but every container has a different one.  There's no intrinsic restriction on Docker containers reaching services running outside of Docker, provided you correctly tell it how to get there.

Comment: @DavidMaze, the service it's trying to post application/xml data to is something custom and works without an issue for other applications that send it HTTP POST requests. I am a bit unsure where I need to be looking to make sure my Docker container can get to my machines localhost network. I was reading about host.docker.internal, but it's unclear to me where that get's defined and/or configured.

Comment: I have figured out that I am trying to `HTTP POST` to the localhost, which is the container. Here is the address I am trying to `POST` to: `http://localhost:8400/tasks`. This is working, but there isn't anything to post to on port 8400 in the Docker container. How can I have `localhost` point to the host machine local network, not the `Docker` container local network? I am gathering the network  bridging has something to do with it in `Docker` configurations, but it's still not clear to me how to go about this.